# How to Test Such Component with Jest and Enzyme in React?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React Scroll to Top component where we add this component Below our Router so that while moving across page we donot maintain scroll position .

I was trying to write Test case for this Component But Jest and Enzyme dosent seem to recognise this as a component when doing shallow rendering. I am using typescript and this is the component.

**scrollToTop.ts**

```
export const ScrollToTop = ({history}: IRouterResetScroll) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unListen = history.listen(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
    return () => {
      unListen();
    }
  }, []);

  return null;
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my unit test strategy, the hardest part for your code to be tested is the `history.listen(handler)`, so we can mock the implementation of `history.listen` method, we defined a `queue` to store the handlers. After mount the component, the mocked history will execute `history.listen` with a function as parameter. This function will be stored in the `queue` we defined before. We can get this function from the queue in unit test case and trigger it manually.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

type IRouterResetScroll = any;

export const ScrollToTop = ({ history }: IRouterResetScroll) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unListen = history.listen(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
    return () => {
      unListen();
    };
  }, []);

  return null;
};

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollToTop } from './';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

describe('ScrollToTop', () => {
  it('should scroll to top', () => {
    const queue: any[] = [];
    const mUnListen = jest.fn();
    const mHistory = {
      listen: jest.fn().mockImplementation(fn => {
        queue.push(fn);
        return mUnListen;
      })
    };
    window.scrollTo = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(<ScrollToTop history={mHistory}></ScrollToTop>);
    queue[0]();
    expect(mHistory.listen).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(Function));
    expect(window.scrollTo).toBeCalledWith(0, 0);

    wrapper.unmount();
    expect(mUnListen).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58786973/index.spec.tsx
  ScrollToTop
    ✓ should scroll to top (39ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.041s, estimated 9s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58786973

Comment: thanks @slideshowp2 really helped can you also explained what and how we did it here it will be of great help

Comment: @INFOSYS Update answer, please check.